# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property in ASP.Net MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a BaseController class inherited from MVC Controller-

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected int A= Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A"]);
    protected int B= Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B"]);

    protected int C= A* B;
}
```

It gives error `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property` during compile.

I don't have any constructor. And that's full code of this class.
Any help?

Comment: Can you initialize C in the constructor? Search for field initializer and constructor order during instantiation, this limitation is related to that topic.

Comment: can you show complete code of BaseController? Have you defined any constructor of this controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message relates to your attempt to assign C the value of A * B.

Try creating a protected contructor that carries out the assignment operation, ensure your sub classes then call this base constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since BaseController is an abstract class, you cannot create an instance of the class. So, you cannot call constructor of the abstract class. But you have to have a constructor to run the following code.

```
protected int C= A* B;
```

So, only way to create a constructor of abstract or base class and call base constructor from derived class, as like follows.

```
public DerivedClass() : base() {
    // Do additional work here otherwise you can leave it empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in short, the field initializers run before any constructor in the inheritance chain. So at that time the object is not yet constructed in this sense, so the non-static members cannot be used.

Check out this related [many time quoted article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/)

If these are some initial values, one solution would be to refactor the `A*B` assignment to use the configuration parameter directly.